# QGIS loop/iterator with python in function editor (field calculator)

Tags: qgis, python, field-calculator

I am trying to create a loop to rename the fields of my attribute table. The fields should start at 1 and increment by one until the end of the table (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,...,n)

my code on the python shell works fine, but not in QGIS, why?

Can anyone help me?

```
def loop (x):
    num = 1
    while num < x:
       print num
       num += 1

loop(188)
```

Comment: What happens in QGIS?

Comment: Nothing happens. Here my code

"""
Define new functions using @qgsfunction. feature and parent must always be the
last args. Use args=-1 to pass a list of values as arguments
"""

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def loop (x):
    num = 1
    while num < x:
       print num
       num += 1

Comment: What else are you expecting to happen besides the number being printed? Your code seems to do exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: Indeed seems to run fine. http://imgur.com/9n69sbQ

Comment: That is the problem, the number is not being printed. I get nothing and my table remains empty. So, if the code is write, I suppose i am writing sometihing wrong in QGIS

Comment: At no point in your code do you try to rename anything. You simply print numbers.

Comment: Yes @Vesanto, the code is right. I have already checked that, but when i paste the same thing in the Function Editor from the Field Calculator in QGIS, and run the function, the table is not updated. All the values remain NULL  http://imgur.com/AUtCZLE

Comment: You can do this a lot easier without defining a custom function. Just use "$rownum" in the field calculator or "@row_number" if using QGIS 2.10.

Comment: If you want to define a custom function, I would recommend reading these first: http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/06/05/qgis-function-editor/ http://nathanw.net/2012/11/10/user-defined-expression-functions-for-qgis/ http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/custom_python_functions.html

Comment: Yes @Vesanto, that works perfect. But what if i want to write an specific code (e.g BES1, BES2, BES3, BES4, ... etc)

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, are you wanting to rename field/column names or simply change the attribute value of a given field attribute(s)?

Comment: Let's see @artwork21
1) I have created a new Field/Column (Type = text/string) in my attribute table.
2) I want to give to every feature a new value/name (CODING). This is: 
polygon 1 --> name BES1
polygon 2 --> name BES2
polygon 3 --> name BES3
etc....
I want to write a script for that. How can i do that?

Comment: Where is the "BES" text coming from another field or just a repetitive text you want to place in front of an incremented number?

Comment: Then you would just do: 'BES' || @row_number

Comment: I would also recommend reading the "How to ask a question" post, I think you would have got help a bit quicker if your question had been more specific. http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @artwork21: Text is just a repetitive text i want to place in front of an incremented number

Comment: @Vesanto: perfect, that solves the problem by using the functions already given. But the question is remains without an answer, why the script doesn't work? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The script works fine. You are using it in the wrong place. That is not a custom function. It is a simple python script that does everything you declared it to do.

Comment: I do not think the field calculator UI in QGIS has a python parser, so that is why it does not work.

Comment: You would have to write your own custom python function and call that within field calculator, see tutorial http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/custom_python_functions.html

Comment: @artwork21, that is exactly what i've been trying to do. Create my own function. A function which iterates and increments by one. A function written in python by using the field calculator from QGIS.

Comment: A custom function iterates for each feature in a dataset, so it performs the specific function for each feature. So in your case it would run through 1 to 188 for each feature and return nothing, because your script returns nothing. If you want it to iterate while increasing, you would create a python script using PyQGIS which does that, NOT a custom function. I will submit an example script that does this.

Answer (score 1):

The custom function can be used to run a specific function on each feature in a layer. But this will be feature specific. For more uses for this please see the following posts specifically for this:
http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/06/05/qgis-function-editor/
http://nathanw.net/2012/11/10/user-defined-expression-functions-for-qgis/
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/custom_python_functions.html

If you want to iterate a growing number for each feature superficially using python, you can use a custom script that can be run from the processing toolbox. An example of this would be as follows. This will create an "Increment" attribute that will increase by 1, starting with 1.

```
#Definition of inputs and outputs
#==================================
##[Iterate script]=group
##input=vector
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
#from processing.core.VectorWriter import VectorWriter
import processing
#print "Start"
layer = processing.getObject(input)
#layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
provider = layer.dataProvider()
fields = provider.fields()
caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
#Delete increment attribute if it exists
class_field_index = layer.fieldNameIndex('increment')
if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.DeleteAttributes:
  res = layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes( [ class_field_index ] )
layer.updateFields()
nElement = 0
if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddAttributes:
  res = layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("increment", \
    QVariant.Int) ] )
layer.updateFields()
class_field_index = layer.fieldNameIndex('increment')
feats = processing.features(layer)
nFeat = len(feats)
writers = []
increment_no = 0
for inFeat in feats:
    #Loop through all the features
    progress.setPercentage(int(100 * nElement / nFeat))
    increment_no += 1
    attrs = { class_field_index : increment_no }
    fid = inFeat.id()
    #Write the increment number to the feature currently being looped on
    layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({ fid : attrs })
#print "Finish"
```